# Nativescript build failed

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to get my app on an android device. When I run

```
tns run android
```

I get this error :

```
/Users/coreelements/Projects/nativescript/myapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:32: AAPT: error: resource
drawable/icon (aka nl.coreelements.myapp:drawable/icon) not found.FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
```

I've already tried regenerating the app and splashes :

```
tns resources generate icons src/images/appicon.png
tns resources generate splashes src/images/appicon.png
```

What am I missing? I've also tried to buid/run in App Studio.

Comment: Did you make any changes to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your `App_Resources/Android/src/main`? Would you mind sharing what you have in that file?

Comment: `rm -rf platforms` and then rebuild the app. Also, make sure that the command has successfully generated icons in each folder in `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res`. Sometimes when passing smaller image not all densities will be generated which will cause this error.

Comment: Yeah .. kinda figured it out .. So the AndroidManifest.xml has a line android:icon="@drawable/icon" , but when you use tns resources generate icons src/images/appicon.png .. then appicon.png will be transformed and transferred to the drawable folders. So the right notation would be android:icon="@drawable/appicon"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just wrapping up the answer from @fransyozef:*

`App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` should point to the right drawable, in this case replacing `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` with `android:icon="@drawable/appicon"` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above did not work for me, what did work is change
`android:icon="@drawable/icon"` to `android:icon="@drawable/fileName"`, so replace /icon with /fileName of the image that is stored there.

Comment: Update: after experiencing crushes again, i completely remove that line and had no problems afterwards. So try to remove the line completely also